# Resetting multiple react Context API states at ones instead of creating resting action for each of them?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have about 5 separate context api states that I want to rest after logging out from app, since they casing lots of issues any idea how to rest them redirecting doesn't seem to be doing much, and I don't want to refresh, this issue is my log out function will logout the user from server and simply redirect to main page but the state is still in the memory ?

```js
 const SignOut = () => {
    signOut(auth)
      .then(() => {
        // Sign-out successful.
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        snackbar.Msg(error, 'A signout error has happened.');
      });
    history.push('/');
  };
```

Comment: Do you mean reset? You can update the state that the contexts provide.

Comment: Could you post an answer ?